# How to validate a property (via IncludeProperties) within a specific ruleset (via IncludeRuleSets) with FluentValidation?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Spent a day on searching an answer.

I have the following validator (please note that there are different rules for **AgeMin** property depends on RuleSet.):

```
class WeirdValidator : AbstractValidator<TestClass>
{
    
    public WeirdValidator()
    {
        public const string CustomRuleSet = nameof(CustomRuleSet);

        RuleFor(instance => instance.AgeMin).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Empty error. {PropertyName}").ScalePrecision(2, 3).WithMessage("Scale error. {PropertyName}");
        RuleFor(instance => instance.FirstInt).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Empty error. {PropertyName}");

        RuleSet(CustomRuleSet, () => {
            RuleFor(instance => instance.AgeMin).Empty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} must be empty.");
            RuleFor(instance => instance.SecondInt).NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} must not be empty.");
        });
    }
}
```

and the following test class:

```
class TestClass
{
    public decimal AgeMin { get; set; }
    public int FirstInt { get; set; }
    public int SecondInt { get; set; }
}
```

FluentValidation allows us to combine validators:

```
                var result = validator.Validate(instanceToValidate, opt => {
                opt.IncludeRuleSets(WeirdValidator.CustomRuleSet);
                opt.IncludeProperties(nameof(instanceToValidate.AgeMin));});
```

But it does not work as I expected. it is not intersection of rules, but consequent actions: at first applying all rules from **CustomRuleSet** and then rule for defined property. I need validation of only selected property of only selected ruleset.
I am sure that there is a very simple and elegant solution but it does not illuminate my way yet.

**Question**:
How to validate a specific property within a specific ruleset?

Comment: I'm not hugely familiar with this usage but I'm observing the same behaviour; If you specify a rule set and a property, it executes the rule set and any rule for the specified property in the validator. I couldn't see anything in the FV issues list about it, if a solution isn't forthcoming it'd be worth raising as an issue.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I seem I found the answer and will post an answer.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer. I'd still consider raising it as an issue, as reading the usage of IncludeRuleSets to me indicates it should only execute rules in the rule sets specified. If you were including `default` or IncludeRulesNotInRuleSet I'd expect the observed behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several days of pain and tears I found a very bad looking solution but, nevertheless, working.

```
var validator = new WeirdValidator();

var ruleDescriptor = validator.CreateDescriptor();
var rulesOfMember = ruleDescriptor.GetRulesForMember(nameof(instanceToValidate.AgeMin));                
var exactRule = rulesOfMember.FirstOrDefault(c => c.RuleSets.Contains(WeirdValidator.CustomRuleSet));

var errorList = exactRule.Validate(
   new ValidationContext<TestClass>(instanceToValidate, new PropertyChain(),
   new RulesetValidatorSelector(WeirdValidator.CustomRuleSet)));
```

The main idea was to find the exact rule for exact property and to execute only one. It turned out that **IValidationRule** has own **Validate/ValidateAsync** methods.

If someone knows better/more elegant solution, you are welcome.

Comment: my IValidationRule does not have Validate methods, i am using version 10.0.0. Curious what version you using, or if you found a more optimal code?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom IValidatorSelector, and use it when creating the validation context.You can use provided factories in `FluentValidation.ValidatorOptions.Global.ValidatorSelectors` to create the desired selectors.

```
public class FluentValidatorCompositeValidatorSelector : IValidatorSelector
    {
        private IEnumerable<IValidatorSelector> _selectors;

        public FluentValidatorCompositeValidatorSelector(IEnumerable<IValidatorSelector> selectors)
        {
            _selectors = selectors;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(IValidationRule rule, string propertyPath, IValidationContext context)
        {
            return _selectors.All(s => s.CanExecute(rule, propertyPath, context));
        }
    }
```

This will filter all rules that does not satisfy **ALL** selectors.

Answer (score 1):

I added the whole thing into an extension method to simplify its use. Hopefully, there will be a better solution in the future. Here's the extension method if anyone needs it for some reason.

```
public static class ValidatorExtensions
{
    public static async Task<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync<T>(
        this IValidator<T> @this,
        T instance,
        IEnumerable<string> properties,
        IEnumerable<string> ruleSets,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var memberNameValidator = ValidatorOptions
            .Global
            .ValidatorSelectors
            .MemberNameValidatorSelectorFactory(properties);

        var ruleSetValidator = ValidatorOptions
            .Global
            .ValidatorSelectors
            .RulesetValidatorSelectorFactory(ruleSets);

        var validationContext = new ValidationContext<T>(
            instance,
            new PropertyChain(),
            new FluentValidatorCompositeValidatorSelector(new[] {
                memberNameValidator,
                ruleSetValidator
            }));

        var validationResult = await @this.ValidateAsync(validationContext, cancellationToken);

        return validationResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Thanks man, you saved me quite a lot of trouble.* -- please credit the post you used as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing, it's not clear who you were thanking.